# Отображение View по-разному в зависимости от роли пользователя WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Всем привет. Суть проблемы. Есть пользователи с разными ролями, например: **админ**, **модератор**, **юзер**.

Я хочу иметь возможность ограничить то, что пользователи могут видеть на основе их роли. Т.е. на одной и той же **View** могут быть скрыты, заблокированы или же вовсе появится новые элементы управления, в зависимости от роли текущего пользователя.

Как такую задачу решить максимально гибко и правильно в контексте паттерна MVVM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На мой взгляд, имеет смысл создать иерархию моделей представления:

```
abstract class BaseRoleVm { ... }
class UserRoleVm : BaseRoleVm { ... }
class ModeratorRoleVm : BaseRoleVm { ... }
class AdminRoleVm : BaseRoleVm { ... }
```

Затем для каждой неабстрактной ViewModel создать по представлению (для переиспользования кода в представлении можно использовать стили, контролы, словари ресурсов).

В основном окне нужно будет завести свойство типа `BaseRoleVm`, которому будет присваиваться нужный наследник:

```
class MainVm
{
    public BaseRoleVm Role { get; set; }

    void UseAdminRole()
    {
        Role = new AdminRoleVm();
    }
    ...
}
```

Такой подход позволит легко вносить изменения в представления/модели представления ролей, обеспечит их независимость друг от друга, предоставить возможность добавлять/удалять роли без вмешательства в логику работы основного окна.

**UPD**

Вот небольшой пример на основе словарей ресурсов:

Модели представления (лежат в папке ViewModels):

```
public abstract class BaseRoleVm : BaseVm
{
    public abstract string Name { get; }
}

public class AdminRoleVm : BaseRoleVm
{
    public override string Name
    {
        get { return "Админ"; }
    }
}

public class UserRoleVm : BaseRoleVm
{
    public override string Name
    {
        get { return "Юзер"; }
    }
}

public class MainVm : BaseVm
{
    public BaseRoleVm SelectedRole
    {
        get { return _selectedRole; }
        set { SetField(ref _selectedRole, value); }
    }
    private BaseRoleVm _selectedRole;

    public BaseRoleVm[] Roles { get; }

    public MainVm()
    {
        // формировать список или создавать нужную модель представления можно через MEF или Reflection.
        // тогда вы не будете зависеть от перечня ролей
        Roles = new BaseRoleVm[]
        {
            new AdminRoleVm(),
            new UserRoleVm(),
        };

        SelectedRole = Roles.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Представления (лежат в папке Views)

```
// содержимое файла "AdminRole.xaml" (тип Resource Dictionary)
<ResourceDictionary ...>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AdminRoleVm}">
        <TextBlock Text="Админское представление"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>

// содержимое файла "UserRole.xaml" (тип Resource Dictionary)
<ResourceDictionary ...>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:UserRoleVm}">
        <TextBlock Text="Представление юзера"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>

// главное окно
// содержимое файла "Main.xaml" (тип Window)
<Window ...>  
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainVm/>
    </Window.DataContext>  
    <Window.Resources>
        <helpers:ViewModelTemplateSelector x:Key="ViewModelTemplateSelector"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Roles}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRole}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedRole, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ViewModelTemplateSelector}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

И простейший селектор шаблонов:

```
public class ViewModelTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var itemType = item.GetType();

        var resourceDictonary = new ResourceDictionary
        {
            Source = new Uri(string.Format(
                "pack://application:,,,/{0};component/Views/{1}.xaml",
                itemType.Assembly.FullName,
                itemType.Name.Replace("Vm", string.Empty)))
        };
        return resourceDictonary
            .Values
            .OfType<DataTemplate>()
            .SingleOrDefault(_ => ReferenceEquals(_.DataType, itemType));
    }
}
```

На уровне представления роли никак не связаны между собой. `ContentControl` использует написанный `ViewModelTemplateSelector` для поисков нужных шаблонов. Происходит примерно следующее:

1. У `ContentControl` меняется `Content` (сработало PropertyChanged)
2. `ContentControl` вызывает у `ViewModelTemplateSelector` метод `SelectTemplate` и передает туда `Content` в качестве `item`
3. `ViewModelTemplateSelector` находит файл с представлением на основе имени типа и достает оттуда `DataTemplate`.
4. `ContentControl` отображает `Content` с использованием найденного `DataTemplate`

Comment: А как в зависимости от типа View model, подсунуть ту или иную View для отображения?

Comment: Можно через ContentControl и ContentTemplateSelector, можно через MergedDictionaries, если у вас используется ResourceDictionary в качестве представления.

Comment: А какой вариант более предпочтительный и гибкий?

Comment: @sp7 мне больше нравится вариант с DataTemplateSelector. Обновил вопрос. Посмотрите на пример.

Comment: Не совсем понятно как это все связывается на уровне разметки, можно, пожалуйста, как-то пояснить? Я как понимаю в разметке главного окна у нас идет еще биндинг на MainVm, например так: <Window.DataContext> <local:MainVm/> </Window.DataContext>

Comment: Далее для UserRoleVm и AdminRoleVm  у нас есть свои View, которые в лежат в папке Views. Эти View представляют собой Windows окна и в них уже содержится полноценная разметка для нужной роли или разметка для каждой роли определяется в ResourceDictionary?

Comment: @sp7, да, главное окно связано с моделью представления через DataContext. Просто я опустил этот момент. Представления в моем примере - это не Window, а ResourceDictionary. Разметка определяется в DataTemplate, который лежит в этом словаре.

Comment: @sp7 обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое, с этим разобрался. А если не много усложнить задачу и попытаться сделать следующее: добавить элемент `Menu` при клике по элементу которого, должно открыться новое окно. Но окно так же в зависимости от роли текущего пользователя должно отображаться по-разному. Как такое можно сделать, подскажите, пожалуйста?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32657/discussion-between-vlad-and-sp7).

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю для каждого типа пользователей создать свой класс с набором необходимых полей.

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить свойство Role во вьюмодель типа enum, во вьюхе биндить доступность контролов (IsEnabled, Visbility) к этому свойству. Если не хочется возится с конверторами и тригерами, можно во вьюмодель запихать свойства типа CanPressButtonX для простоты. В чем конкретно проблема то?

Comment: Проблема в том, что View достаточно сложная и на ней может размещаться большое кол-во разных элементов управления.

Comment: Логику размещения контролов все равно куда то запихать придется. Если различия совсем радикальные что вьюхи не узнать, то можно и разные вьюхи под разные роли заюзать. Это может быть проще чем загаженые логикой вьюхи сразу под все роли.

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал так:

1. Получил список разрешенных элементов для роли (из бд, xml и т.д.)
2. код

   ```
   foreach (var rule in rules) {
       var control = FindName(rule.ProgramModule) as Control;
       if (control != null)
           control.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
   }
   ```

   где `ProgramModule` - это наименование элемента.

Некоторая сложность в том, что необходимо все элементы делать collapsed (ну либо идти от обратного, делать все элементы разрешенными и выключать те, которые запрещены).
Просто если пялиться в mvvm по фен-шую, то лепить "вьюхи" под каждую роль - но это очень избыточно, особенно если контроллов на форме "море".